# apply two textures on a plane in Three.js

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to add two textures at the same time on a plane? Or a cube?

I would like to apply one texture at the top half of a plane and a different one at the bottom half.

Something like this:

[image]

this is what I set so far

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2, 2 );
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load( 'textures/stone.png');
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 4, 4 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How is your plane defined?

Comment: @TheJim01 updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to segment your geometry, and use multi-materials.

This means you'll use the `widthSegments` and `heightSegments` parameters of [`PlaneGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/PlaneGeometry) to define a plane with more than just two faces. This is necessary because each face can only have one material (unless you're doing some seriously fancy blending).

Once you have a segmented plane, you can assign the `materialIndex` of each face to point to a separate material.

You'll also define your mesh using an array of materials, rather than just one--each face's `materialIndex` references an index in the materials array.

The last thing to do, which I'll leave up to you, is to adjust the face UVs and texture repeating/wrapping to achieve the effect you're seeking.

If you have further questions on this topic, leave a comment, and I'll try to address them.

```js
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.js
// https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js

/**********************/
/*   Initialization   */
/**********************/

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {
    canvas: document.getElementById( "view" ),
    antialias: true,
  alpha: true
} );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 28, 1, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 50;

camera.add( new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, Infinity ) );

scene.add( camera );

var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.addEventListener( "change", render );

/**********************/
/* Populate the Scene */
/**********************/

var texLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var tex1 = texLoader.load( "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/WallRGB.png", render ); // bricks
var tex2 = texLoader.load( "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/NGC772_-_SDSS_DR14.jpg", render ); // space

var mat1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: tex1 } );
var mat2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: tex2 } );

// First, segment your geometry however you need it.
// This one is segmented into 1 horizontal segment with 2 vertical segments.
var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 10, 10, 1, 2 );

// Next you need to set up your faces to use specific materials.
planeGeo.faces[ 0 ].materialIndex = 0;
planeGeo.faces[ 1 ].materialIndex = 0;
planeGeo.faces[ 2 ].materialIndex = 1;
planeGeo.faces[ 3 ].materialIndex = 1;

// You can create a mesh using an array of materials, referenced by materialIndex.
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeo, [ mat1, mat2 ] );

scene.add( mesh );

/**********************/
/*   Render Function  */
/**********************/

function render () {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
render();

/**********************/
/*   Animation Loop   */
/**********************/

function animate () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
}
animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge">
    <title>TEST</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    
  <canvas id="view" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px black solid;"></canvas>

    <script src="test.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Can ask you something else? Those tiles are 75x75px. What if I want a to place a third tile that is 75x10px (same with, but much shorter) between the bigger ones (across the red line). Is that possible?

Comment: @MatíasCánepa First, you can't think of it as "pixels." GL measurements are unit-less, though they all use the same units. In the end, you can compute pixel sizes, but it's better to not think of them that way.

Comment: @MatíasCánepa Regarding adding a third "row", `PlaneGeometry` subdivides its rows/columns evenly. This means that in a 3-way split, each row will be 33% of the total height. You could dig into the `planeGeo.vertices` and change their positions to better suit the effect you desire, but remember the unit-less nature. If `tex1` is 100px tall, and `tex2` is 75px, the faces for the `tex2` row should be composed to be 75% the height of the `tex1` row faces. Does that make sense?

Comment: Would it be viable just to make two planes and add them to a group?

Comment: Or three? I mean this can go on forever, so using the tessellation / topology of the plane may not work. Rendering with multimaterial yields multiple draw calls anyway, why not simply compose this shape out of multiple meshes?

Comment: @pailhead Your point is valid, since three meshes is conceptually easier than manipulating geometry. Still, it might not fit with what Matías has in mind. I can't immediately think of any reason to _not_ split this concept into multiple meshes, but rather than assume, I took the question at face value.

Comment: Understood, but he didn't mention "mesh" or "geometry" just "plane" and "cube". I'm only really curious about, if the OP already is familiar with `THREE.Mesh` and scene graphs (there is a line that says `scene.add(mesh)`, what prevented him from concluding that another simple `scene.add(mesh2)` could do this? Maybe it's not the user's fault, maybe threejs is made too simple nowadays that it confused people?

Comment: Running the code snippet, it seems that images rendered are cropped. Is there some way to render an image fully onto each half ?

Comment: @formatkaka You would need to adjust the face UVs to reference the correct texture coordinates. If you are trying to do this and running into trouble, please create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @TheJim01's answer, the code below will, adjust the UV coordinates on the floor geometry so that they will tile:

```
var tileSize = 24;
var textureSize = 256;
var floorScale = tileSize/textureSize;
floorGeometry.faceVertexUvs.forEach(layer => layer.forEach((face, i) => {
    const base = layer[i % 2];
    if (i % 2) {
        face[0].x = 0;
        face[0].y = floorScale;
        face[1].x = floorScale;
        face[1].y = floorScale;
        face[2].x = floorScale;
        face[2].y = 0;  
    } else {
        face[0].x = 0;
        face[0].y = 0;          
        face[1].x = 0;
        face[1].y = floorScale;
        face[2].x = floorScale;
        face[2].y = 0;
    }
}));
```